# Explicit equations' normal vector

Tags: calculus

In the wikipedia article for normal vectors there it says I could parametrise the function by $z=f(x,y)\rightarrow r(x,y)=\langle x,y,f(x,y)\rangle$ and compute $\partial / \partial x \times \partial / \partial y$. In the example of a sphere the normal vector along the x,y plane is $\langle ...,...,0\rangle$ not $\langle ... , ... , 1 \rangle$ like demonstrated.

I've used the computer wolframalpha for a while and I can't get the answer to a cross product of "partial derivative of sqrt(x^2+y^2 -1) wrt x and partial derivative of sqrt(x^2+y^2 -1) wrt y" . What steps am I doing wrong!

[Wiki page: normal (geometry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y96x9.png)

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? How far do you get with those partial derivatives? Or our you stuck on the cross product?

Comment: well I tried to calculate a flux out of the sphere with the form $\langle x,y,f(x,y) \rangle$ instead of $\langle u\cos(v),u\sin(v), ... \rangle$

Comment: $\displaystyle \int^{1}_{-1}\int^{1}_{-1} \int^{\sqrt(x^2+y^2-1)}_{-\sqrt(x^2+y^2-1)} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WolframAlpha looks good to me, check [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%2Fdx+%7Bx%2C+y%2C+sqrt%281+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%7D%29+cross+%28d%2Fdy+%7Bx%2C+y%2C+sqrt%281+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2+%29%7D%29). Note that $x'(y) = y'(x) = 0$ in the result because $x$ and $y$ are not functions of each other and that the function whose graph is a sphere is $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$.

Comment: If the sphere is centered at the origin, I still just dont see why the resulting normal vector from this is pointing upward...

Comment: @user719062 the vector is not pointing upward. The fact that $z \neq 0$ just means it is not parallel to the x-y plane, not that it is pointing upward. For it to be pointing upward you would need a vector like $(0, 0, z)$, $z > 0$. Indeed at $x = y = 0$ is the only place where it's pointing upward (at the pole of the sphere).

Comment: I remember the normal vector should be in the $x-y$ plane since the sphere is centered at the origin. Then $(1,0,0)$ should have a normal vector that is $\langle 1, 0,0 \rangle $ ..

Comment: @user719062 this formula doesn't work for the points at the hemisphere where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ because the derivative is not defined there.

Comment: Oh, right, well I don't get why come the derivative is not defined there if we just calculated the partials. Ok I will try and figure that out thanks very much.